# Construct a dynamic class name in ember js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Using Ember.js - in my handlebars template, I would like to be able to "build" a css class based on multiple properties I have stored.

My Data looks like this:

```
App.AddonChoices.FIXTURES = [
  { id:101, title: 'Bark' },
  { id:102, title: 'Teal' },
  { id:103, title: 'Tangerine' }
]

App.AddonItem.FIXTURES = [{
      id: 100,
      name: 'Scratch Pad',
      class: 'scratch',
      selected: null,
      choices: [101, 102, 103] //['Bark', 'Teal', 'Tangerine']
    }]
```

I would like to build my css based on id rather than title because the names change from time to time (but ya cant use pure numbers in classes) so I was aiming for some html that looks like this

```
<li class='scratch101'>Bark</li>
```

with the **class** being a combination of **addonItem.class** and **addonChoices.id**

I know I can just add a class to AddonChoices, but I would like to avoid that as it is extra data that I dont really need to track.

Any ideas on how to construct the class name within handlebars template?

**UPDATE:**
I ended up solving it using views... with some help from @louiscoquio

Created a view and included the function **tileClass** in the **classNameBindings**:

```
 App.Tiles = Ember.View.extend({
  type:null,
  id:null,
  tagName:'li',
  classNameBindings: ['type', 'title', 'tileClass'],
  tileClass: function(){
  return  this.get('type') + this.get('id')
  }.property('type', 'id')
 });
```

Call the view within my template like so:

```
    {{ view App.Tiles 
     titleBinding= 'addonChoices.title'  
     idBinding= 'addonChoices.id'
     typeBinding= 'addonItem.class' }}
```

which renders this html

```
<li title="Kiwi" id="ember494" class="ember-view scratch scratch105 Kiwi"></li>
```

Comment: Have you looked at creating a computed property for `AddOnItem` that builds the correct class name string?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using ember data, as you're using `FIXTURES`.

Given these `AddonItem` and `AddonChoices` models:

```
AddonItem = DS.Model.extend({
  choices: DS.attr('hasMany', 'App.AddonChoices'),
  class: DS.attr('string')
});

AddonChoices = DS.Model.extend({
  owner: DS.attr('belongsTo', 'App.AddonItem'),
  title: DS.attr('string')
});
```

You can define a computed property in the `AddonChoices` model like this:

```
AddonChoices.reopen({
  ownerClassAndId: function() {
    return this.get('owner.class') + this.get('id');
  }.property('owner.class', 'id')
});
```

You can notice the property depends on `owner.class` and `id`. It means the property will be recomputed each time the `owner.class` or `id` changes.

Anyway, I think this computed property should not be defined in the model, but rather in the controller (or even the view, for this use case).

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. I am starting to get it. I did also figure out how to do it in the view... taking some hints from your answer.

Comment: You're welcome! You have some issues with your code. Firstly, you muse use `this.get('theproperty')` to access a property (ie use `this.get('type')` instead of `this.type`. Then, your `tileClass` should be recomputed when the type or the id changes, so you have to specify it: `tileClass: function() { ... }.property('type', 'id'). If you don't do that, your view will not be updated when its type changes. Anyway, glad to help !

Comment: Thanks again! I updated my code example to reflect your fixes.